# How can I use different script in .gitlab-ci.yml depending on pushed branched

Tags: angular, git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have following setting in `gitlab-ci.yml` file for build

```
build_app:
  image: node:10
  stage: build
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 5 minute
    paths:
      - ./dist
  script:
#    - mkdir app
#    - cp package*.json ./app
    - npm ci
#    - COPY . . ???
    - npm run build --prod
```

As you can see my build is always with `--prod` flag and when I test on test server it also starts with `prod` data

How can I make script to use `ng build --prod` when I push to`master` branch and `ng build --configuration=stage` when I push to`dev` branch ?

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html

Comment: @KamilCuk not so clear for me as I'm not an expert in gitlab ci cd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a shell script to check the current branch that caused the ci/cd to run:

```
- case "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" in 
  "master") ng build --prod; ;;
  "dev") ng build --configuration=stage; ;;
  esac
```

or maybe more readable with a simple if else:

```
- if [ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" = "master" ]; then
       ng build --prod;
  elif [ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" = "dev" ]; then
       ng build --configuration=stage;
  fi
```

Answer (score 1):

There is only one yaml file per repository. But you could define what part of the script is run on what branch by using the key word only (for more details, go to documentation).
This should look like this:

deploy_master:

stages:
-build

build:
stage: build
script:
-"HERE YOUR COMMAND"
only:
- master

deploy_dev:

stages:
-build

build:
stage: build
script:
-"HERE YOUR COMMAND"
only:
- dev